# SSH bind to multiple addresses / ports at once (the -L flag)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I currently have two SSH commands,

```
ssh -L 15000:some-instance.amazonaws.com:5432 <bastion server>
```

and

```
ssh -L 15001:some-other-instance.amazonaws.com:5432 <bastion server>
```

As a result, I can connect to `some-instance` and `some-other-instance` at `localhost:15000` and `localhost:15001`, respectively.

Is there a way to do this with one command? When I need to use both at the same time it's a bit annoying to have to have 2 command lines open.

My understanding of how this works is pretty limited so I apologize if my wording is inaccurate!

Comment: You can use multiple `-L` with the same ssh command. Is there something else about it?

Comment: I just.. never thought to try that haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put both `-L` options on the same command

```
ssh -L 15000:some-instance.amazonaws.com:5432 -L 15001:some-other-instance.amazonaws.com:5432 <bastion server>
```

Comment: I cannot believe I never thought to try this haha. For some reason I figured it could only be used once per command.